# Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $\{e_1, \dots , e_n , \dots \}$ an orthonormal countable set.

Tags: functional-analysis

Given $f \in H^*$, show that $f(e_n) \rightarrow 0$. Although it seems easy, I'm having a little bit of trouble to prove it. I tried to use Riesz Theorem, but couldn't find anything. Any tip? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hint: $\exists y\in H s.t f(x)=< x,y>$

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your space is separable and the orthonormal set is dense in it. By Riesz' theorem the form $f$ has a corresponding vector $v \in H$ such that
$f (e_n) = (v, e_n)_H$ (the scalar product in $H$). This vector has
"coordinates" wrt. $\{ e_1, \ldots, e_n, \ldots \}$ given precisely by $(v,
e_n)_H$. You can use the representation wrt. this basis and [Parseval's
identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_identity) to conclude.

Comment: Actually, I could solve the exercise assuming what you said, Miguel. But my problem is excactly that we don't have H separable =[

Comment: But $E=\text{span} \{e_n\}$  is Hilbert and if $f \in H'$ then its restriction to $E$ is in $E'$. You can then consider the corresponding $v \in E$ by Riesz' theorem and finish with Parseval, again in $E$.